# God seldom opens one door that he doesn't close another

Tags: idioms, negation, sentence-meaning

I'm reading [An Unquiet Mind: A Memoir of Moods and Madness](https://books.google.com/books?id=3O82iMI7bqwC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22god%20seldom%20opens%20one%20door&source=bl&ots=aHnIbaCafh&sig=LksVqxt8CNPDeXy9NtPe7aJfcEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lonBuITUAhVKxYMKHS3mBUgQ6AEIODAI#v=onepage&q=%22god%20seldom%20opens%20one%20door&f=false).  I don't understand this part:

> I couldn't help thinking, with more than a trace of bitterness, that God seldom opens one door that he doesn't close another.

(should I put 'its' or 'the' here?)Preceding sentence is I couldn't help thinking with more than a trace of bitterness, and (same question) following sentence is However, I couldn't afford not to..

I've seen this only in an affirmitive form(when god closes~~ he opens~~), and while I think I might know what it means.. oh no.. I don't know what it's saying. Some double negative thing..term for this.. Could you explain this with an emphasis on the usage of 'that'?

Comment: @Josh no, he is referring to this book https://books.google.com/books?id=3O82iMI7bqwC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22god+seldom+opens+one+door&source=bl&ots=aHnIbaCafh&sig=LksVqxt8CNPDeXy9NtPe7aJfcEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lonBuITUAhVKxYMKHS3mBUgQ6AEIODAI#v=onepage&q=%22god%20seldom%20opens%20one%20door&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD wow, what a world. It is the book I'm reading. So what does it mean?

Comment: It means you can't catch a break.

Comment: It is a **profoundly pessimistic inversion** of the commonly heard hopeful expression **'God seldom closes one door that He doesn't open another'** -- simply by exchanging the places of 'open' and 'close', the author twists the optimistic sentiment into one of deep pessimism, while also alerting the reader to this twist by using the word 'bitterness' in the first part of the sentence. Within the context of the book you are reading, which our member DavePhD so kindly found and referenced here, such ***extreme negation of hope*** is a cardinal sign of severe (even dangerous) depressive illness.

Comment: @EnglishStudent — Please follow the instructions in the Comment box (or re-read the site guidelines if you use a mobile).  "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." Whatever other people do, this is what the site requests. If you ignore it you are breaking the SE model.

Comment: @David this comment though rather long is intended to be an observation that serves as an explanation regarding OP's question **and not an answer as defined in this website** -- if we are allowed a certain number of characters per comment then why not use them to express myself? If I write the same thing as an answer, somebody will call it a matter of opinion instead of a 'proper answer with citations and links to other examples of established usage, etc.' It had happened so often that somebody advised me either to write a full scholarly answer or *express my 'informed opinion' as a comment.*

Comment: @David I fully understand your point of view, and you can verify that in addition to such comments that apparently serve as answer ***I have posted a large number of proper answers*** wherever they can be well supported with quotations from published sources; but some answers though valid cannot be supported with evidence for various reasons: unless the official position that answers (but not comments) must be comprehensive and fully supported with citations is somewhat relaxed, the only place where I can contribute in response to OP's question *in such cases* would be in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence from [An Unquiet Mind: A Memoir of Moods and Madness](https://books.google.com/books?id=3O82iMI7bqwC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22god%20seldom%20opens%20one%20door&source=bl&ots=aHnIbaCafh&sig=LksVqxt8CNPDeXy9NtPe7aJfcEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lonBuITUAhVKxYMKHS3mBUgQ6AEIODAI#v=onepage&q=%22god%20seldom%20opens%20one%20door&f=false) is:

> I couldn't help thinking, with more than a trace of bitterness, that God seldom opens one door that he doesn't close another.

I think it would make more sense to say:

"...seldom does God open one door without closing another".

Comment: Upvoted for the citation. Certainly this quote is disquieting — or should I say *un*quieting?

Comment: @StevenScotten she dropped her lithium pills while praying in a cathedral.  So she bitterly thought that God closed a door. (At least that's my interpretation).

Comment: that's my interpretation too. It's a bitter twist on what you've established is a much older expression.

Comment: Yes, it is a **profoundly pessimistic inversion** of the commonly heard hopeful expression **'God seldom closes one door that He doesn't open another'** -- within the context of the book you so kindly found and referenced here for our benefit, such ***extreme negation of hope*** is a cardinal sign of depressive illness.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard this as some variation on "when one door closes, another one opens." Yes, usually with God doing the opening and closing. This is the first time I've encountered it with the opening of one door as the first part.

From a secular point of view, I take it purely as "any lost opportunity creates other opportunities." It's at least hard to argue with the proposition that if you can't go one way you ought to look for other directions to go rather than spending emotional energy over the lost opportunity.

The above is not an interpretation of the phrase you asked about, but I hope it contains useful context so I'm keeping it in. I suspect that the line from Jamison was written to intentionally contrast against the adage I've heard.

I read "that" in your example as "so that" or "in order that". It's a construction I see in religious (formal and/or archaic *sounding* even if not actually formal or archaic) usage eg "Jesus died **that** we all may have eternal life."

Comment: Edited to make clear that my interpretation was not of the phrase from the original question.

Comment: There is a quote from 1852 "When the Lord closes one door, then, and seldom till then, He opens another" https://books.google.com/books?id=aT8EAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA256&dq=god+seldom++one+door&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt7aKOvoTUAhXD8CYKHYbTDYkQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=god%20seldom%20%20one%20door&f=false

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't help thinking, with more than a trace of bitterness, that God seldom opens one door that he doesn't close another.

If I believed in God, I might use this sentence, or concept, to talk about an unfortunate coincidence in my own life, which was that around the same time my first child was born, my PhD advisor died.

I would not have had to be profoundly depressed to come to this conclusion.

That is my personal opinion.  I hope this example helps you understand the paragraph in the book you are reading.